# RadGridView Thousands Separator for Decimal Column While Editing

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I can add thousands separator for my decimal column like this:

```
var decimalColumn = radGridView1.Columns["DecimalColumn"] as GridViewDecimalColumn;
decimalColumn.ThousandsSeparator = true;
decimalColumn.FormatString = "{0:n0}";
```

It works fine. But When I'm in editing mode and I type for example `1000000` then will be not thousands separator while editing. So the user may be confused.

How to apply `thousands separator` to a decimal column while editing? Is there any built-in feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a thousands separator, indeed, it is appropriate to set the column's  **ThousandsSeparator** property to true. This is expected to affect the editor as well.

However, **RadGridView** gives you access to the editor in the **CellEditorInitialized** event. Hence, you can enable it explicitly for the editor:

```
        public RadForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridViewDecimalColumn decimalColumn = radGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"] as GridViewDecimalColumn;
        decimalColumn.ThousandsSeparator = true;
        decimalColumn.FormatString = "{0:n0}"; 

        this.radGridView1.CellEditorInitialized += RadGridView1_CellEditorInitialized;
    }

    private void RadGridView1_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        GridSpinEditor spinEditor = e.ActiveEditor as GridSpinEditor;
        if (spinEditor!=null)
        {
            spinEditor.ThousandsSeparator = true;
        }
    }
```

[image]

I hope this information helps.

Comment: while typing in spin editor it will not show the Thousands Separator. Just after editing and after typing it will appear. I need it while typing.

Comment: better maybe, how can I get `TextBoxItem` of `GridSpinEditor`, so I can fire a TextChanged Event for it.

Comment: The RadTextBoxItem can be accessed via the RadSpinEditorElement:                
           
       
                RadSpinEditorElement element = spinEditor.EditorElement as RadSpinEditorElement;    
       
                RadTextBoxItem tbItem = element.TextBoxItem;